# Dropdown menu using html and css hides behind the h1?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, z-index

*This is the first time i am building a drop down menu for the navigation.*
The **functionality** of the dropdown menu **works fine**.
But **my dropdown appears behind the h1(it's a hero section)**

- I tried using z-index with greater value on many places but none
  worked.
- I tried using z-index with lesser value on the h1 and greater value
  on the drop-down none worked

> i read many related post in the same forum and tried the suggested
> solution but none worked for me.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/sputniksweetheart/pen/eYMdZyM?editors=1100)

```css
.drop-down {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-down__button:hover+.drop-down__list {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.drop-down__list {
  margin-top: 2.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: -2.7rem;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  min-width: 30rem;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-2rem);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.drop-down__list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.drop-down__link:link,
.drop-down__link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-down">
  <a href="#" class="drop-down__button">What We Do</a>
  <ul class="drop-down__list">
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">Social Media Marketing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">Web Development</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">App Development & Promotion</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">Strategy Marketing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down__list-item">
      <a class="drop-down__link" href="#">Lead Generation</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1 class="heading-primary margin-bottom--s">
  Start growing your business with
  <span class="">digital marketing.</span>
</h1>
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to make drop-down-menu to appear infront of the h1?

Comment: Actually the hover was working correctly, the background of that hovering div is transparent, if you add background color it will be working as per you expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot to set the dropdown backgroundcolor:

```
.drop-down__button:hover + .drop-down__list {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0);
  background-color: white;
}
```

By making this adjustment it should work as expected.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: But when i try to hover on the drop-down-list it gets invisible, How to navigate through the drop-down-list?

Comment: Would you mind opening another question for that?

Answer (score 1):

The drop down menu is not under the h1: it's an optical illusion...

add `background-color: white;`  to `.drop-down__list` to see the effective z-placing